# Determine shared memory area between the parent and the child after child runs exec()

Tags: c, linux

I am student developer and beginner in C programming language. I have a task and I did not find a clear solution according to my level. I want to run exec() function  in child process. I created parent and child using fork(). It's OK.  I know they are two different process. I need to notice starting time to parent process. Before child works exec() command, I need to determine shared memory area and starting time should be inside shared memory area. When the child process is completed , I need to calculate between starting time and ending time using gettimeofday() method. How can I determine shared memory between the parent and the child and calculate time interval if the child has run exec()?

My example code is here :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void  ChildProcess(void);                /* child should work exec() command family */
void  ParentProcess(void);               /* parent process prototype */

void  main(void)
{
     pid_t  pid;

     pid = fork();
     if (pid == 0){
          ChildProcess();
     }
     else{
          wait(NULL);
          ParentProcess();
     }
}

void  ChildProcess(void)
{
     // something
     printf("   *** Child process ***\n");
}

void  ParentProcess(void)
{    
     // something
     printf("*** Parent process  ***\n");
}
```

Comment: When you use `exec`, it completely replaces the existing process. File descriptors are (Unless explicitly set `CLOEXEC`) kept in the new process, but it has its own brand new memory space. If you want to have memory share between the new process and the original one, you'll have to use [posix shared memory](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html), `mmap()` the same file in each, old school SYSV shared memory, etc.

Comment: However, that's an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) if you're just looking for how long a child process took to run. Look into [`getrusage()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html) or [`wait4()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait4.2.html).

Comment: I understand. I will try to use posix shared memory method with your advice.